# Is there any temporary location of sql server to save files

Tags: sql

I want to save data to some file and then want to read the data back. 
Is there any way to save the file(txt or excel) on some temporary location in case of SQL server?

Comment: Are you asking about how to take backup ? I mean import/Export ?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, you can do this as follows -

**Export**

If you right click on the database > Tasks > Export Data.

You will have to select a data source - you have a few options here and you can choose the one relevant to you.

**Import**

If you right click on the database > Tasks > Import Data.

*It would be easier to back up your database and just re-run the query you have when need so.*